Connecting Alexa Echo Pop to Ubuntu 24.04
I just purchased an Alexa for my studio and wanted to know if I could somehow connect it to my PC running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?

Connect it to do what? Data transfer? Charging? Do you want to use the Alexa to control Ubuntu? Please [edit] your question and explain what you want the Alexa to be able to do.

Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1513012

I want to use it for like creating folders or turn on and off the pc, but i dont reallt know if that is possibile (sorry for the not very detailed question)
